Unable to display my LWC component in Global Action


I am unable to display my LWC component in Global Action. Below is my metadata file. Also, I tried this community link but still did not work
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007PwITxSAN

More info about LWC global actions: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000Oq9gWSAR
